# What is Prestige in Globulation?

Tags: globulation-2

After winning a game of Globulation2 I get a graph about different statistics. One of these graphs shows Prestige, which I get for upgrading the school. What does Prestige influence? Is it only a statistic or does it make anything in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://globulation2.org/wiki/Prestige

The prestige system is an alternative way of winning Globulation 2. It is intended as a way of ending long games that would otherwise end in stalemate - the team which has greatest prestige when the the total prestige target is reached wins the game.

The prestige system is not well tuned yet, so it is extremely difficult to win the game by prestige. At present, each level 3 school a team owns is worth 50 prestige points and the prestige target depends on how many players there are in the game.

In a game of Globulation 2, prestige scores can be seen in the middle of the top line. The first number is your prestige score, the second number is the current total prestige of all players in the game, and the third number is the total prestige target. When total prestige reaches target amount, player with most prestige wins the game.